# How to pass koa-session data to page components in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, koa

In my NextJS project, I created a custom server with `koa` + `koa-session`, so that I can have some session data per each request, like the code below,

```js
import next from "next";
import Koa from "koa";
import Session from "koa-session";
import Router from "koa-router";

...
const next_app = next({...});
const handle = next_app.getRequestHandler();

next_app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  server.use(Session(server));  // use koa-session middleware
  ...
  router.get("(.*)", async (ctx) => {
    console.log("server.js session: ", ctx.session);
    ...
    // create or update session data
    ctx.session.custom_data += 123;
    
    // but how to pass ctx.session to handle(), then to page components?
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
});
```

As said in the comment, how to pass `ctx.session` data to page components?

Comment: Normally you don't want to blindly expose all data stored in `ctx.session` to the client-side, as it might contain sensitive information. Instead, you might want to explicitly choose what data you want to pass.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks for your comment! I thought it's not necessarily *exposing all data to client-side*, because I just want to use `ctx.session` in `getServerSideProps()`, and this function actually runs on server-side, so not client-side.

Comment: @DevWhoDat can't remember what I did, sorry